# Chrome extension: How to show custom UI for a PDF file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, pdf.js

I'm trying to write a Google Chrome extension for showing PDF files. As soon as I detect that browser is redirecting to a URL pointing to a PDF file, I want it to stop loading the default PDF viewer, but start showing my UI instead. The UI will use PDF.JS to render the PDF and jQuery-ui to show some other stuff.

Question: how do I make this? It's very important to block the original PDF viewer, because I don't want to double memory consumption by showing two instance of the document. Therefore, I should somehow navigate the tab to my own view.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the main author of the [PDF.js Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm), I can share some insights about the logic behind building a PDF Viewer extension for Chrome.

#### How to detect a PDF file?

In a perfect world, every website would serve PDF files with the standard `application/pdf` MIME-type. Unfortunately, the real world is not perfect, and in practice there are many websites which use an incorrect MIME-type. You will catch the majority of the cases by selecting requests that satisfy any of the following conditions:

- The resource is served with the `Content-Type: application/pdf` response header.
- The resource is served with the `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` response header, and its URL contains ".pdf" (case-insensitive).

Besides that, you also have to detect whether the user wants to **view** the PDF file or **download** the PDF file. If you don't care about the distinction, it's easy: Just intercept the request if it matches any of the previous conditions.
Otherwise (and this is the approach I've taken), you need to check whether the `Content-Disposition` response header exists and its value starts with "`attachment`".

If you want to support PDF downloads (e.g. via your UI), then you need to add the `Content-Disposition: attachment` response header. If the header already exists, then you have to replace the existing disposition type (e.g. `inline`) with "attachment". Don't bother with trying to parse the full header value, just strip the first part up to the first semicolon, then put "attachment" in front of it. (If you really want to parse the header, read [RFC 2616 (section 19.5.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.5.1) and [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266)).

#### Which Chrome (extension) APIs should I use to intercept PDF files?

The [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API can be used to intercept and redirect requests. With the following logic, you can intercept and redirect PDFs to your custom viewer that requests the PDF file from the given URL.

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
    if (/* TODO: Detect if it is not a PDF file*/)
        return; // Nope, not a PDF file. Ignore this request.

    var viewerUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('viewer.html') +
      '?file=' + encodeURIComponent(details.url);
    return { redirectUrl: viewerUrl };
}, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
}, ["responseHeaders", "blocking"]);
```

(see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/extensions/chromium/pdfHandler.js for the actual implementation of the PDF detection using the logic described at the top of this answer)

With the above code, you can intercept any PDF file on http and https URLs.
If you want to view PDF files from the local filesystem and/or ftp, then you need to use the [`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) event instead of [`onHeadersReceived`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onHeadersReceived). Fortunately, you can assume that if the file ends with ".pdf", then the resource is most likely a PDF file. Users who want to use the extension to view a local PDF file have to explicitly allow this at the extension settings page though.

On Chrome OS, use the [`chrome.fileBrowserHandler`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/fileBrowserHandler) API to register your extension as a PDF Viewer (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/extensions/chromium/pdfHandler-vcros.js).

The methods based on the webRequest API only work for PDFs in top-level documents and frames, not for PDFs embedded via `<object>` and `<embed>`. Although they are rare, I still wanted to support them, so I came up with an unconventional method to detect and load the PDF viewer in these contexts. The implementation can be viewed at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/4549/files. This method relies on the fact that when an element is put in the document, it eventually have to be rendered. When it is rendered, CSS styles get applied. When I declare an animation for the embed/object elements in the CSS, animation events will be triggered. These events bubble up in the document. I can then add a listener for this event, and replace the content of the object/embed element with an iframe that loads my PDF Viewer.
There are several ways to replace an element or content, but I've used [Shadow DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html) to change the displayed content without affecting the DOM in the page.

#### Limitations and notes

The method described here has a few limitations:

- The PDF file is requested at least two times from the server: First a usual request to get the headers, which gets aborted when the extension redirects to the PDF Viewer. Then another request to request the actual data.
  Consequently, if a file is valid only once, then the PDF cannot be displayed (the first request invalidates the URL and the second request fails).
- This method only works for GET requests. There is no public API to directly get response bodies from a request in a Chrome extension ([crbug.com/104058](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058)).
- The method to get PDFs to work for `<object>` and `<embed>` elements requires a script to run on every page. I've profiled the code and found that the impact on performance is negligible, but you still need to be careful if you want to change the logic.
  (I first tried to use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for detection, which slowed down the page load by 3-20% on huge documents, and caused an additional 1.5 GB peak in memory usage in a complex DOM benchmark).
- The method to detect `<object>` / `<embed>` tags might still cause any NPAPI/PPAPI-based PDF plugins to load, because it only replaced the `<embed>`/`<object>` tag's content when it has already been inserted and rendered. When a tab is inactive, animations are not scheduled, and hence the dispatch of the animation event will significantly be delayed.

#### Afterword

PDF.js is open-source, you can view the code for the Chrome extension at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/extensions/chromium. If you browse the source, you'll notice that the code is a bit more complex than I explained here. That's because extensions cannot redirect requests at the `onHeadersReceived` event until I implemented it a few months ago ([crbug.com/280464](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=280464), Chrome 35).

And there is also some logic to make the URL in the omnibox look a bit better.

The PDF.js extension continues to evolve, so unless you want to significantly change the UI of the PDF Viewer, I suggest to ask users to install the PDF.js's official [PDF Viewer in the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm), and/or open issues on [PDF.js's issue tracker](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues) for reasonable feature requests.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I was able to write a sample that intercepts all the URLs that point to a PDF file. However, I've got a problem then. Not sure, whether it's a problem with PDF.js and/or my XHR code. When I use **PDFJS.getDocument(pdfUrl)** to show the content of the pdf file, I see lots of errors in the log: https://gist.github.com/another-guy/f750b2db3811c0ee7df8 I tried to load PDF as a blob using XHR and then feed it to PDF.js. However, even my XHR requests is successful (HTTP code 200), I get the same html page that runs my script instead of PDF contents. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, looks like my XHR and PDF.js requests are filtered as well. :) Now I also need to distinguish 'regular' browser requests from ones that are made from my extension.

Comment: @keykeeper You should make sure that you add the `types: [`"main_frame", "sub_frame"]` filter as shown in my answer. It's omitted from Marco's answer, but that is wrong, you should only redirect frame requests.

Comment: Спасибо! This helped! YAY!

Comment: Thanks for you complete answer. However, there is still something I don't understand. What's the point of having an official extension which can be installed to Chrome whereas this is already the native and used library?

Comment: @JérômeMével The PDF viewer referenced in my answer is using PDF.js to render PDFs (100% JavaScript). The built-in PDF viewer in Chrome uses PDFium (~100% C++). Besides the difference in language, there are also quite some differences in UI/UX. See my reply to the question "I do not get the difference between the native PDF viewer in Chrome and this one?" from 30 sep 2015 at the user feedback section: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/support

Comment: I currently have some issues with Microsoft Edge that's why I'm investigating on this. I have a form which I set its target to an iframe. So I looked what Chrome is populating to my iframe after POSTing the form. There is 10 JavaScript files loaded, all are written by "The Chromium Authors" and one is actually named "pdf.js". Go to chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/pdf.js in Chrome you will  get the library automatically loaded. So I doubt in that case a 100% C++ code is used.

Comment: @JérômeMével That "pdf.js" you're referring to is bundled with Google Chrome, and part of Chrome's PDF embedding implementation. [This pdf.js file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/browser/resources/pdf/pdf.js) has nothing to do with [PDF.js library](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) from my answer. Note that I said "~100% C++" in my previous comment, because the PDF rendering logic of PDFium is written in C++, and only a tiny part is written in something else (JavaScript) to act as a bridge between the web page and the PDFium.

Comment: @RobW Thanks for your answers, I get it now.

Answer (score 3):

### Custom PDF Viewer

Basically, to accomplish what you want to do you'll need to:

1. Interject the PDF's URL when it's loaded;
2. Stop the PDF from loading;
3. Start your own PDF viewer and load the PDF inside it.

### How to

1. Using the `chrome.webRequest` API you can easily listen to the web requests made by Chrome, and, more specifically, the ones that are going to load `.pdf` files. Using the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` event you can listen to all the requests that end with ".pdf" and get the URL of the requested resource.
2. Create a page, for example `display_pdf.html` where you will show the PDFs and do whatever you want with them.
3. In the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` listener, prevent the resource from being loaded returning `{redirectUrl: ...}` to redirect to your `display_pdf.html` page.
4. Pass the PDF's URL to your page. This can be done in several ways, but, for me, the simplest one is to add the encoded PDF URL at the end of your page's url, like an encoded query string, something like `display_pdf.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fexample.pdf`.
5. Inside the page, get the URL with JavaScript and process and render the PDF with any library you want, like [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

### The code

Following the above steps, your extension will look like this:

```
<root>/
    /background.js
    /display_pdf.html
    /display_pdf.js
    /manifest.json
```

So, first of all, let's look at the **`manifest.json`** file: you will need to declare the permissions for `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking`, so it should look like this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "PDF Test",
    "version": "0.0.1",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["/background.js"] 
    },

    "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"],
}
```

Then, in your **`background.js`** you will listen to the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` event and update the tab which is loading the PDF with the URL of your custom `display_pdv.html` page, like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    var displayURL;

    if (/\.pdf$/i.test(details.url)) { // if the resource is a PDF file ends with ".pdf"
        displayURL = chrome.runtime.getURL('/display_pdf.html') + '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(details.url);

        return {redirectUrl: displayURL};
        // stop the request and proceed to your custom display page
    }   
}, {urls: ['*://*/*.pdf']}, ['blocking']);
```

And finally, in your **`display_pdf.js`** file you will extract the PDF's url from the query string and use it to do whatever you want:

```
var PDF_URL = decodeURIComponent(location.href.split('?url=')[1]);
// this will be something like http://www.somesite.com/path/to/example.pdf

alert('The PDF url is: ' + PDF_URL);
// do something with the pdf... like processing it with PDF.js
```

### Working Example

A working example of what I said above can be found **[HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/rnim3d476b35zou/extension-27770677_-_PDF_Viewer.zip)**.

### Documentation links

I recommend you to take a look at the official documentation of the above specified APIs, that you can find following these links:

- [`chrome.webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

  - [`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest)
- [`chrome.runtime` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime)

  - [`chrome.runtime.getURL` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL)

Comment: The very first prototype of PDF.js Chrome extension was implemented as you described here, but it suffered from two problems: 1) PDFs with the correct MIME-type (`application/pdf`) but without the `.pdf` suffix (even URLs like `http://example.com/file.pdf?whatever`) won't be displayed. 2) Resources that coincidentally end with `.pdf` but are not PDFs are also redirected.

Comment: @RobW I was expecting this exact comment, ahah, but since that you provided a more complete answer and since that explaining the full logic behind the PDF viewer would take several pages, I left my answer "incomplete".

Comment: @RobW by the way, are you sure that checking for `application/octet-stream` MIME-type and `~details.url.indexOf(".pdf")` is correct? What if you load some `"/file.pdf.zip"`? Shouldn't you use a more complete RegExp or something else to check the url?

Comment: I haven't seen file.pdf.zip + `application/octet-stream` in practice (but I have seen file.pdf with this MIME-type). Even if the extension wrongly detects a downloadable file as a PDF, the user can just download the file via the UI.